# Ordering data before grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am selecting two fields, 'name' and 'address' from a table of multiple entries. Each record is a home address belonging to each name. A new record is created every time an address is changed and all I need to do is generate a list of names and their latest addresses.

To do this I am selecting name and address grouped by name, which gets me a list of names and addresses. But how can I ensure that the address returned is the latest? There is a date field that I can use but I'm not sure how to sort and group at the same time.

Comment: Add a boolean column that is marked if a record is last. So you would be able to select last rows without `GROUP BY` at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

don't use group by, it's not a good idea, you can tried to use left join like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.adress
FROM table AS t1 LEFT JOIN table AS t2
ON (t1.name = t2.name AND t1.date < t2.date)
WHERE t2.date IS NULL;
```